# rCharts Parallel Coordinates Plot with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, parallel-coordinates

I need parallel coordinates plot with interactivity in shiny. [This](http://ramnathv.github.io/rChartsParCoords/) is the plot that I want and [this](http://ramnathv.github.io/rChartsShiny/) is a solution of producing `rCharts` in `shiny`.

Comment: You can make this kind of plot with `ggplot2` quite easily, and `shiny` can work with `ggplot2`. So the answer to your question is yes, you can make this kind of plot using Shiny. To get a more useful answer, please narrow down your question to a specific problem. Right now your question is simply too vague.

Comment: The key thing here is interactivity, which you can not achieve with `ggplot2` + `shiny`.

Comment: Your question is not clear that this is what you want. Only after reading the two links your provide, one can deduce this. Making this explicit in your question makes it more clear.

Comment: Post your question on http://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts. rCharts does provide bindings for d3js based parallel coordinates plot.

Answer (score 3):

If you need interactivity, have a look at either [ggvis](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis) or [D3.js](http://d3js.org/). `ggvis` is an R based solution, and D3.js uses Javascript. The first is still quite experimental, D3 is already very mature and can produce very nice interactive graphs (rendered client-side). This would whoever mean you need to learn JavaScript.

Comment: I need parallel coordinates plot, so `ggvis` is not an option. And yes, I do not intend to learn JavaScript.

Comment: I do not know of another solution except `ggvis` or directly using `JavaScript` that can get you both the parallel coordinates plot and the interactivity you require.

Comment: rCharts provides bindings to d3js based parallel coordinates plot http://rcharts.io/parcoords/